# configure zipkin to store in MySQL

Tags: mysql, zipkin

I am currently trying to configure Zipkin to store data in MySQL.

I am running zipking using jar zipkin-xx.xx.x-exec.jar

MySQL connection has been tested. after I start Zipkin with the parameters：

java -jar zipkin-xx.xx.x-exec.jar STORAGE_TYPE=mysql MYSQL_USER=root

it is not working, no data created in the database.

Have I running it wrong?

Lu.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know why it did not work.

Because we are running zipkin on windows servers.

We need to set these:

STORAGE_TYPE=mysql MYSQL_USER=root

as environment variables(not java -jar params)